# separate logging for various subclass

Tags: logging, log4j2

I am expecting logs from a class and subclass of this first class. Lets say-

"*com.example*" and "*com.example.logger*"

I need to create a separate log files for these two.
i have created two appenders for these two

**Appender1 - for "com.example" except "com.example.logger"**

**Appender2 - specific for "com.example.logger"**

Tried to write AsyncLogger as -

```
<AsyncLogger name="com.example" level="WARN">
    <AppenderRef ref="Appender1" />
</AsyncLogger>

<AsyncLogger name="com.example.logger" level="DEBUG">
    <AppenderRef ref="Appender2" />
</AsyncLogger>
```

But, this is not working as logs from "*com.example.logger*" is also going to Appender1 File.

Need to add something in AsyncLogger1 to blacklist "*com.example.logger*" from  going to Appender1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define logger for `com.example.logger` first with `additivity` param set to false.

E.g.

```
<AsyncLogger name="com.example.logger" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="Appender2" />
</AsyncLogger>

<AsyncLogger name="com.example" level="WARN">
    <AppenderRef ref="Appender1" />
</AsyncLogger>
```

Comment: glad to help :)